# Switch language within code listing using lstlisting

Tags: lstlisting

I'm using lstlisting to insert Java code in my text. But within the same listing I want to change font color for a few lines while continuing with the same listing format. My objective is to only highlight the lines that cause compilation and/or runtime failure in red color.

I understand that there won't be any syntax highlighting in those special lines (because the color would be red throughout those lines).

I have tried escapeinside and \textcolor{red} to change color to red but that changes the text format to the regular text format and also gets rid of new lines that are there in the code.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I got it. I am using moredelim parameter. Like this -

```
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=java, basicstyle={\small\ttfamily}, moredelim={[is][\color{red}]{STARTRC}{ENDRC}}]
class Test{
  private String name; 
STARTRC     default String id;//will not compile.ENDRC
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

The text within STARTRC and ENDRC is now being displayed in red color with everything else same as the other part of the listing.